# angularjs resource slash parameters

Tags: angularjs, rest, resources, uri

I am using $resource to make a rest api call.
My call to that resource is like that :

```
 Client.get({parametres : param}
```

My problem is that param contains "\" character, that make the call fail with

> 400 Bad Request

response.

How can I escape the "\" character?

Thanks.

Comment: typically with another backslash : ` a\\b`

Answer (score 0):

`encodeURIComponent` should do the trick.

> The encodeURIComponent() method encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

As per: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

```
Client.get({ parameters: encodeURIComponent(param) }
```

Comment: Could you also explain the solution?

Comment: thanks, I came up with that solution too. works great.